# JS: extracting href and src attributes URLs from DOM as absolute

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, path, absolute-path

I'm using JQuery to extract the src and href from elements in the DOM as follows:

```
var mysrc;
$('img[src]').each(function (index) {
   mysrc = $(this).attr('src');
   // convert relative path to absolute url
});
```

However many of these paths to images or in link href are relative, not absolute. Sometimes they start from the web root like this: /blah/img.jpg and something they go up or down one directory: ../blah/img.jpg.
I'd like to make all these paths as absolute URLs, and I haven't found a script to do this. I know how to extract the host of a given page from the location, but then i'm missing all the logic that would convert those relative paths into absolute urls. Any idea where I could find something to do this in Javascript/JQuery, or how I should proceed.

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.prop()` returns the calculated property value, ie the absolute path.
Instead of using a jQuery method, you can also use a plain `this.src`.

```
$('img[src]').each(function (index) {
   // var mysrc = $(this).prop('src');  //<-- jQuery
   var mysrc = this.src;
   // Why do you want to get the absolute path, by the way?
});
```

Comment: Cool! Thanks. Actually found this would work also: $('#your_img').get(0).src -- but this is probably the same thing, correct?

Comment: @Loic. `.get(0)` returns the first matching DOM element of the jQuery object. So, `$(this).get(0) === this`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to get the app context - I don't think it's available in javascript. You might know it per app though.

In JSP you can get context like this:

var contextPath = "<%=request.getContextPath()%>";

other server-side languages should have similar constructs. Having context you could form absolute path like

Absolute path = window.location - contextPath + relativeURL;

so, if your URL is

http://mysite.com/foo/bar and context is http://mysite.com/foo/ and the relative path is "../somedir/mypic.jpg" then the absolute path would be

/bar/../somedir/mypic.jpg